# Using global variables with functions in Python

Tags: python

I am working with python functions to make a simple text based word guessing in python. But I am facing problems with local variables defined within a function and I don't know which is right way to get data of that particular local variable or perform action from another function to that local variable which is defined within another function, whether use of `global` keyword.

I can use `global` but some experienced geeks advise to avoid. What is the right way to do the same. It sows `ask` is not defined. Please suggest to me some best practice to do the same.

```
import random
def get_random():
    random_word = random.choice(open('sowpods.txt', 'r').read().split())
    return(random_word)
def board():
    hidden_word = get_random()
    print("Welcome to Hangman!")
    place = ["_" for i in list(hidden_word)]
    print(" ".join(place))
    ask = input("Guess the letter.  ").upper()
    return(ask)

def asking_letters(ask):
    return(ask)

get_random()
board()
asking_letters(ask)
```

P.S. I am a beginner and i have problem with OOP and functions.

Comment: You should learn how to pass parameters to functions and assign their returned values to variables. This is a fundamental skill not teachable on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The advice you've gotten is quite sound: you should strive to avoid using `global` when possible. To make a file-scoped global, you can just define the variable outside of all functions/classes. Looking at your code, though, it seems like everything you're trying to accomplish *should* be handled by the `board()` function. It seems like you need to try to use a loop to repeatedly ask and keep score.

But, to answer your explicit question, consider this example:

```
import random

myList = []

def get_random():
    random_word = random.choice(open('sowpods.txt', 'r').read().split())
    return(random_word)

def addWordToList():
    word = get_random()
    myList.append(word)

print myList # Should print []

for i in range(10):
    addWordToList();

print myList # Should print a list with 10 words from sowpods.txt
```

Here, you can see that I've updated `myList` every time I called `addWordToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your assing_letters doesn't do anything currently. I think you want to refactor the code in board but I'm not sure:

```
import random
def get_random():
    random_word = random.choice(open('sowpods.txt', 'r').read().split()])
    return(random_word)
def board():
    hidden_word = get_random()
    print("Welcome to Hangman!")
    place = ["_" for i in list(hidden_word)]
    print(" ".join(place))

def assing_letters():
    ask = input("Guess the letter.  ").upper()
    return(ask)

get_random()
board()
ask=assing_letters()

print(ask)
```

Answer (score 0):

Notes on your code:

1. you don't need to inclose returned variables in '()'
2. using global variable is fine for small scripts and when you know what you're doing
3. you don't have to call `get_random` again since it's already called inside `board`
4. `assing_letters` is useless in this context!

I guessed the correct code might be like this:

```py
import random


def get_random():
    """Return a random word from ``sowpods.txt`` file"""
    random_word = random.choice(open('sowpods.txt', 'r').read().split())
    return random_word


def play():
    """Start the game:

    Takes an input word from the user then check if he guessed the random word or not"""

    hidden_word = get_random()
    print("Welcome to Hangman!")
    place = ["_" for i in list(hidden_word)]
    print(" ".join(place))
    user_guess = input("Guess the letter.  ").upper()

    if user_guess == hidden_word:
        return "You guessed it right!"
    return "You failed!"


play() # start the game
```